# TDD with python book, functional test doesnt find assertRegex

Tags: python, django

Following the test driven development with python book I got stuck
I have tried several different imports but still nothing.. anyone?

Error

```
$python manage.py test functional_tests
ERROR: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later (functional_tests.tests.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/coelhao/DjangoProjects/superlists/functional_tests/tests.py", line 45, in
test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
self.assertRegex(edith_list_url, '/lists/.+') AttributeError: 'NewVisitorTest' object has no attribute 'assertRegex'
```

Code

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest

class NewVisitorTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
        # .....

        # When she hits enter, the page updates, and now the page lists
        # "1: Buy peacock feathers" as an item in a to-do list table
        inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        edith_list_url = self.browser.current_url
        self.assertRegex(edith_list_url, '/lists/.+')
        self.check_for_row_in_list_table('1: Buy peacock feathers')

        # ....
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming you are on Python 2 - then use [`assertRegexpMatches`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegexpMatches) instead of `assertRegex`.

[`assertRegex`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegex) was introduced in Python 3:

> Changed in version 3.2: The method assertRegexpMatches() has been
>   renamed to assertRegex().

Answer (score -1):

There is no such assertion as `assertRegex` - perhaps you mean `assertRegexMatches`?

The unittest docs are here: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase

Comment: You might want to look in the Python 3 documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRegex